# How to find number of duplicates in an array?

Tags: c++

I have a given array and I need to determine how to find the number of duplicates in it. I have to do this using nested for loops and can not use vectors. I have tried it so far and I get 3, but the answer should be 2 since only the numbers 4 and 7 repeat. I see why I am getting 3 since it checks 4 two times but I can't seem to figure out how to adjust it so It never checks 4 again once it found a match.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int num_elements = 12;
    int numbers[num_elements] = { 2, 6, 7, 4, 5, 4, 1, 8, 9, 0, 7, 4 };

    unsigned int numduplicates = 0;    
    for(int i = 0; i < num_elements; ++i){
        int oneCounterMax = 0;
        for(int j = i + 1; j < num_elements; ++j) {
            if((numbers[i] == numbers[j]) && (oneCounterMax < 1)) {
                ++numduplicates;
                ++oneCounterMax;
            }       

        }
    }       
    cout << numduplicates << endl;
}
```

Comment: You may sort you array first, then code to skip checked numbers is easy.

Comment: I believe I am allowed to sort the array. In this case I would get {0,1,2,4,4,4,5,6,7,7,8,9} but its the skipping the next checked number part that has me stuck

Comment: You find 3 because you don't check if current number is already count as duplicate : the first 4, you find a duplicate, and the second one also. You have to check if the current number isn't in the begin of array. If it is, it's already count as duplicate, so no need to continue, you can pass to next number

Comment: An other solution is to check with previous numbers (and if present skip it).

Comment: @ernie To clarify what you are asking; are you asking how many different duplicates are found, or are you asking for how many numbers in total are duplicates? For example: { 1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3 }; The answer to first question would be 3 since there are 3 duplicates, and the 2nd answer would be that there are 8 numbers that are duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way would be to use `std::vector` and `std::map` as already mentioned by others. But since you can only use nested loops and arrays here's an example that works:

```
const int num_elements = 12;
int numbers[num_elements] = { 2, 6, 7, 4, 5, 4, 1, 8, 9, 0, 7, 4 };
int counter = 0;

for ( int i = 0; i < num_elements; i++ ) {
    for ( int j = i + 1; j < num_elements; j++ ) {
        if ( numbers[j] == numbers[i] ) {
            counter++;
            for ( int k = 0; k < i; k++ ) {
                if ( numbers[k] == numbers[j] ) {
                    counter--;
                    break;
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}

cout << counter << endl;
```

It will print `2` and not `3`. Simply, when we find a duplicate, we go back and check if we already met this number.

Answer (score 3):

You find 3 because you don't check if current number is already count as duplicate : the first 4, you find a duplicate, and the second one also. You have to check if the current number isn't in the begin of array. If it is, it's already count as duplicate, so no need to continue, you can pass to next number

```
int main() {
    const int num_elements = 12;
    int numbers[num_elements] = { 2, 6, 7, 4, 5, 4, 1, 8, 9, 0, 7, 4 };


    for(int i = 0; i < num_elements; ++i){
        int oneCounterMax = 0;  
        bool notAlreadyCheck = true;  

        for(int j = 0; j < i-1; ++j) {
            if (numbers[i] == numbers[j]){
                notAlreadyCheck = false;
            }
        }
        if (notAlreadyCheck) {    
            for(int j = i + 1; j < num_elements; ++j) {
                if((numbers[i] == numbers[j]) && (oneCounterMax < 1)) {
                    ++numduplicates;
                    ++oneCounterMax;
                }       
            }
        } 
    }       
    cout << numduplicates << endl;
}
```

Comment: Although it is the much,  much longer way to do it, this is basically what we are expected to do. I just tried stuff out with the suggestions and basically go this same exact thing. Thank you !

Comment: @ernie it's just a naive implementation. Free to you to improve ;) happy that help you

Comment: @ernie If this solved your problem don't forget to accept.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the answers are good enough, but not striving too far from your solution, there is also a clever trick to be had!:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int num_elements = 12;
    int numbers[num_elements] = { 2, 6, 7, 4, 5, 4, 1, 8, 9, 0, 7, 4 };

    unsigned int numduplicates = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_elements; ++i) {
        int counter = 0; // changed name
        for (int j = i + 1; j < num_elements; ++j) {
            if (numbers[i] == numbers[j]) { // changed condition
                ++counter; // only increment counter
            }
        }

        if (counter == 1) { // added if statement
            ++numduplicates;
        }
    }
    cout << numduplicates << endl;
}
```

Instead of only counting 1 of the duplicates (with `oneCounterMax`), we count all of them. Then later we check if the number we counted is exactly 1.

This does 2 things:

- We counted at least 1 duplicate, so there is a duplicate of the current number. but...
- If we counted more then 1 duplicate, we don't increment the duplicate counter, because it will already be done later on in our iteration, when we count again for the second to last duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map, for instance, where key is number[i] and value is occurrences of number[i].

```
std::map<int,int> m;
std::map<int,int>::iterator it;
for(int i = 0; i < num_elements; ++i) {
   const int key = numbers[i];
   int value = 0;
   it = m.find(key)
   if (it != m.end()) {
      ++value;
   }  
   map.insert(std::make_pair(key,value));
}
```

Comment: _"I have to do this using nested for loops and can not use vectors."_

Comment: map != vectors, btw you're right for "nested loops"

Comment: yes maps are not the same as vectors but normally when someone says they can't use vectors it means it is homework and they typically cannot use any standard containers

Answer (score 0):

Once you sort the array, instead of counting duplicates, count the number of transitions where `a[i-1] != a[i] && a[i] == a[i+1]`, which will give the number of duplicate elements.  You have to guard for the boundaries though.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to sort the array,then skip the repeated elements  and increase the value of **`numduplicates`**

```
int main() {
    const int num_elements = 12;
    int numbers[num_elements] = { 2, 6, 7, 4, 5, 4, 1, 8, 9, 0, 7, 4 };

    sort(numbers,numbers+12);//sorting
    int  numduplicates = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < num_elements; ++i){
        if((i+1)<num_elements && numbers[i] == numbers[i+1]) {
            ++numduplicates;
            while((i+1)<num_elements && numbers[i] == numbers[i+1])
               i++;
       }       
    }       
    cout << numduplicates << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowed to sort the array, you can write something like this:

```
std::sort(numbers, numbers + num_elements);

int k = 0;
while (k < num_elements - 1) {
   int i = 1;
   while ((k + i < num_elements) && (numbers[k + i] == numbers[k])) 
      i++;
   if (i > 1)
      ... // numbers[k] is a duplicate with multiplicity i
   k += i;
}
```

Comment: For sorted array you can count duplicates just in one pass without inner loops

Comment: My solution uses passes over elements only once, i.e., its complexity is O(n), even though with inner loop. Your solution is fine, but it does not distinguish elements being in a sequence 2x, 3x, 4x, ... It depends whether you need to count multiplicities or not.

Answer (score 0):

First sort the array and then iterate over this sorted array. Use a bool flag to save the current state about whether this number has been counted as a duplicate number.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int num_elements = 12;
    int numbers[num_elements] = { 2, 6, 7, 4, 5, 4, 1, 8, 9, 0, 7, 4 };

    std:sort(numbers, numbers+num_elements);
    int duplicate_count = 0;
    bool duplicate = false;
    for(int i = 1; i < num_elements; i++)
    {
        if(numbers[i] != numbers[i-1])
            duplicate = false;
        else if(numbers[i] == numbers[i-1] && !duplicate)
        {
            duplicate_count++;
            duplicate = true;
        }
    }
    cout << "duplicate count: " << duplicate_count << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just use int to remember value and you do not need boolean flag and complex conditions

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like homework in which case your teacher may be unhappy with this approach even though it doesn't use `vector`.

Given the input array:

```
int numbers[num_elements] = { 2, 6, 7, 4, 5, 4, 1, 8, 9, 0, 7, 4 };
```

You can find the unique size of the array by using a [`set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set), because a `set`:

> Is an associative container that contains a sorted set of **unique** objects of type `Key`

In C++14 you can build the `set` like this:

```
const auto numduplicates = num_elements - set<int>(cbegin(numbers), cend(numbers)).size();
```

[<kbd>Live Example</kbd>](http://ideone.com/OpGbNl)

In C++11 you can build the `set` like this:

```
const auto numduplicates = num_elements - set<int>(numbers, next(numbers, num_elements)).size();
```

And before that you could build the `set` like this:

```
const auto numduplicates = num_elements - set<int>(numbers, numbers + num_elements).size();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest implementation for sorted array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int numbers[] = { 2, 6, 7, 4, 5, 4, 1, 8, 9, 0, 7, 4 };

    auto b = std::begin( numbers );
    auto e = std::end( numbers );
    std:sort( b, e );
    auto ne = std::unique( b, e );
    std::cout << "duplicates:" << std::distance( ne, e ) << std::endl;
}
```

or by one loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int numbers[] = { 2, 6, 7, 4, 5, 4, 1, 8, 9, 0, 7, 4 };

    auto b = std::begin( numbers );
    auto e = std::end( numbers );
    std:sort( b, e );

    int dups = 0;
    int v = *b++;
    for( auto it = b; it != e; ++it ) {
       if( v != *it ) v = *it;
       else ++dups;
    }
    std::cout << "duplicates:" << dups << std::endl;
}
```